# NSInteger not equal to long?

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, long-integer, nsinteger

I am trying to parse some json data in Cocoa and I am having troubles with the NSInteger data type. The json string has some long values that I assign  to NSInteger properties. Unfortunately the assigned NSInteger value differs completely from the long value. Why is that so? NSInteger is defined as typedef long NSInteger. I could have assigned the long value to a long property but I just would like to know why I can't assign it to an NSInteger.

```
    -(void)parseData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSError*err=nil;
    NSDictionary*jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    _userID=(NSInteger)[jsonData valueForKeyWithoutNSNull:@"id"];
}
```

The _userID is a NSInteger.
The value retrieved from the dictionary is a long.

Comment: Update your question with real code and real data. Be clear about what values you are seeing.

Comment: I added a snippet from the parse method,hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply cast an `NSNumber` (or even `NSString`) to an `NSInteger`. Dictionaries and other collection classes can't store primitive types like `NSInteger`.

Assuming your dictionary contains numbers and not strings then you need:

```
NSNumber *number = [jsonData valueForKeyWithoutNSNull:@"id"];
_userID = [number integerValue];
```

Comment: Yeah you are right I totally forgot that, thank you :) .

Comment: @ok404 Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer to indicate it solved your problem.